# make a directory only readable by root.

Tags: linux, apache

I would like to make a folder on my Apache Server only readable by root. 
Does anybody know how to do it, or the numerical value for this comand in order to set it in my FTP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that the directory is owned by root and it has only read access for the owner. Make sure execution access is disabled.

The command would be like this(run loged as root):

```
chmod 400 folder
```

Answer (score 0):

If the directory is owned by root, the permissions would be 400

`sudo chmod 400 directory`